# How to evaluate $\arctan(1/\tan(-x))$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to evaluate the value of $$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\tan(-x)}\right)$$ by using the expression of $x$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Problem statements are discouraged, so please show your thoughts, what you have tried, where you are stuck, etc.

Comment: I will do it next time. I just totally have no idea with it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you for the assurance. :) Keep contributing to the site as per the guidelines, and it will be a great experience learning and interacting with the community. All the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that by [**trigonometric identities**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Inverse_trigonometric_functions)

$$\arctan u + \arctan \dfrac{1}{u}=
 \begin{cases} 
 \dfrac \pi 2,  \text{if }u > 0 \\
 - \dfrac \pi 2,  \text{if }u < 0 
 \end{cases}$$

therefore

- for $\tan(-x)>0$

$$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\tan(-x)}\right) = \dfrac \pi 2-\arctan(\tan(-x))$$

- for $\tan(-x)<0$

$$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\tan(-x)}\right) = -\dfrac \pi 2-\arctan(\tan(-x))$$

Also recall that

$$\arctan (\tan y)=y \iff -\dfrac \pi 2<y<\dfrac \pi 2$$

otherwise we need to add some integer multiple of $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

$\arctan(\cot(-x))=\arctan\left(\tan\left(\dfrac\pi2+x\right)\right)=n\pi+\dfrac\pi2+x$

where $n$ is an integer such that $$-\dfrac\pi2<n\pi+\dfrac\pi2+x<\dfrac\pi2$$

$\cot(-x)$ can also be written as $-\cot x=\tan\left(x-\dfrac\pi2\right)$

Answer (score -1):

If $y=\arctan\frac1{\tan(-x)}$, then $\tan y=\frac 1{\tan(-x)}=\cot(-x)=\tan(\frac\pi2-(-x))$, which suggests that $y=x+\frac\pi2$ up to a multiple of $\pi$. We conclude that $$\arctan\frac1{\tan(-x)}=x+\frac\pi2+k\pi$$
where $k$ is  the unique integer (if it exists) that makes this value $\in(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$.